# mod_proxy module in tomcat for development environment

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy

I've a webapp deployed on tomcat server A, which is dependent on a couple of wars deployed on a different tomcat server B. I've a proxy web server (apache) which I've configured to redirect requests to servers A or B based on the url pattern.

As a developer for webapp A, I don't want to have additional step to bring up (or maintain) proxy server to appropriately redirect requests to my host(not constant) for development purposes.

Is there a way to use mod_proxy module (and use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives) in my tomcat itself which is hosting development instance A, so that it gives me the functionality of proxy server (like apache does).

I asked this question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250105/mod-proxy-module-in-tomcat-for-development-environment) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  The mod_proxy is an Apache module written in native code, Tomcat is pure java http implementation and doesn't have this option.